# vim: shortcut to move to the beginning of line and switch from normal mode to insert mode (shortcut of "^" + "i")

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

In vim, is there a shortcut that can achieve what both "^" (move to the beginning of line) and "i" (switch to insert mode) can achieve? SO basically, a shortcut that's shorter than "^" then "i".

Comment: Is that so *hard* to use Vim's help? `:help i` and bingo! you have your answer! That "new" brand of laziness consisting in never ever doing any effort to find an answer by oneself and using Google or worse, asking random strangers and wait for 2, 3 or 10 freaking hours without doing any research in the meantime… I. Just. Can't. Understand. How did we come to this?

Comment: @romainl Thank you for the advice. I actually googled it before I came here to ask. And I didn't know ":help i" will give me the answer, to be frankly. But still, thank you for your advice. And I will learn the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try uppercase <kbd>I</kbd>, that is pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.